Distribute realized geometry based on field values
I created a custom node that generates trees, based on certain input values: height, n_branches, random seed etc. I would love to be able to distribute these trees on points, and to supply each with a value based on the points attributes (e.g, height can depend on a calculation based on the position field).
This sounds like instance of points but obviously instances will not work: I want to have variation between the trees so they are not instances. Is there any other way to achieve this - distributing realized geometries, with variations based on field values of their points?

It's much easier for us to answer if you post screenshots or images explaining what you're trying to accomplish and what you have already tried.

so you need to build it with that in mond from the beginning. this os the geometry nodes mentality/workflow. you could try to hack your way with repeat zone, but that shortcut will cost you your performance. erin has a good video on that https://youtu.be/URWuNhg5ZNk?si=WLgGNx4pOFYKAe8Y (it shows you how to make a try generator that has variance and not instanced...)

(Using Blender 4.2.0)

The behavior of the Instance on Points node can be simulated with a Repeat Zone to "spawn" unique objects. The field values of the spawning points are recovered using a Sample Index node. Successive spawned objects are accumulated using a Join Geometry node. For the demonstration, the size of a cube is a function the distance to origin of the spawning point. The Cube node can be replaced by the Group Node generating a tree.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)
